# Don't fail test if filtering returned no tests in subproject

Tags: android, gradle, junit4, android-instrumentation, android-junit

My `connectedDebugAndroidTest` fails with

> com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[SM-A310F - 7.0] FAILED
>
> No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).

The problem here is that I

1. execute the task on a parent project which has two sub projects `:lib` and `:mobile` and
2. run the instrumentation test with a filter ([annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner#typical-usage)).

As I run on the parent project, the child projects are tested one after another. The filter does find tests to run in `:lib` but there are no test satisfying the filter in `:mobile`. This is perfectly okay for me but the test and thus the CI fails.

How can I instruct the test to not fail if no tests were found (especially in the case where there *are tests found*, but not in each of the sub projects)

My current gradle call is like this:

```
gradlew.bat --continue connectedDebugAndroidTest
-P android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation=android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest
```

actually, I use a custom annotation but it serves the same purpose as `@FlakyTest` so I just tested with than one to rule out problems with my custom annotation.

The relevant excerpts taken from the same instrumentation log are:

#### The part dealing with the first subproject:

```
I/RemoteAndroidTest: Running am instrument -w -r   -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest com.example.lib.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner on SM-A310F - 7.0
V/ddms: execute: running am instrument -w -r   -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest com.example.lib.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
V/InstrumentationResultParser: com.example.lib.activities.MainActivityTest:
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testOnCreate
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.example.lib.activities.MainActivityTest
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
1 tests on SM-A310F - 7.0
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testOnCreate
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.example.lib.activities.MainActivityTest
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: Time: 1,362
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: OK (1 test)
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
I/XmlResultReporter: XML test result file generated at TEST-SM-A310F - 7.0-lib.xml. Total tests 1, passed 1, 
V/ddms: execute 'am instrument -w -r   -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest com.example.lib.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' on '31006b2f91c74311' : EOF hit. Read: -1
V/ddms: execute: returning
V/ddms: execute: running pm uninstall com.example.lib.test
V/ddms: execute 'pm uninstall com.example.lib.test' on '31006b2f91c74311' : EOF hit. Read: -1
V/ddms: execute: returning

....
```

#### The part dealing with the first subproject:

```
....
I/RemoteAndroidTest: Running am instrument -w -r   -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest com.example.mobile.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner on SM-A310F - 7.0
V/ddms: execute: running am instrument -w -r   -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest com.example.mobile.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: Time: 0,001
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: OK (0 tests)
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1
V/InstrumentationResultParser: 
0 tests on SM-A310F - 7.0
I/XmlResultReporter: XML test result file generated at TEST-SM-A310F - 7.0-mobile.xml. Total tests 0, 
V/ddms: execute 'am instrument -w -r   -e annotation android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest com.example.mobile.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' on '31006b2f91c74311' : EOF hit. Read: -1
V/ddms: execute: returning

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[SM-A310F - 7.0] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
05:00:56 I/XmlResultReporter: XML test result file generated at TEST-SM-A310F - 7.0-mobile.xml. Total tests 1, failure 1, 
05:00:56 V/ddms: execute: running pm uninstall com.example.mobile.test
05:00:58 V/ddms: execute 'pm uninstall com.example.mobile.test' on '31006b2f91c74311' : EOF hit. Read: -1
05:00:58 V/ddms: execute: returning
05:00:58 V/ddms: execute: running pm uninstall com.example.mobile
05:01:00 V/ddms: execute 'pm uninstall com.example.mobile' on '31006b2f91c74311' : EOF hit. Read: -1
05:01:00 V/ddms: execute: returning

> Task :mobile:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: My current workaround is that I added a dummy test to the second project which satisfies the filter but this is more a hack than a solution